# Can't connect to X11 window in raspberry pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, putty, xserver, xming

I'm trying to run My Java Program

```
final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
 mux_a = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_02, "MUX_A", PinState.LOW);
 mux_b = gpio.provisionDigitalOutputPin(RaspiPin.GPIO_03, "MUX_B", PinState.LOW);
```

I have done like

```
sudo java -jar Sample1.jar
```

but it throws an Exception as no protocol specified.

> java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as DISPLAY variable.

I have tried:

```
unset DISPLAY;
export DISPLAY=:0;
export DISPLAY=:0.0'
```

but nothing works out.

But It works fine while calling it from the Putty in my windows system. Suggest me where I'm missing

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/281651/not-able-to-run-simple-java-swing-program-on-raspbian-on-raspberry-pi-2-headless